# convert text sentences to a comma separated vector

Tags: r

I have a dataframe x:

```
> x
        id type
1 13159355  traffic s
2 13159356 suspicious
3 13159357      crash
4 13159358  traffic s
5 13159359    parking
6 13159360  traffic s
```

I would like to make each row of x$type be a vector so that, for example, `x[1,2]` would return `"traffic", "s"` just like if I did `c("traffic", "s")`

Tried:

```
> x$type <- gsub("\\s", ", ", x$type)
> x
        id type
1 13159355 traffic, s
2 13159356 suspicious
3 13159357      crash
4 13159358 traffic, s
5 13159359    parking
6 13159360 traffic, s
```

But if I select `x[1,2]` a single string is returned and not a chr vector.

How can I change all sentences in x$type to be a chr vector or words?

Comment: Use `strsplit` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description, it seems the OP wanted a `list` column.  For this, we can split the column 'type' by one or more spaces (`\\s+`)

```
x$type <- strsplit(x$type, "\\s+")
x[1,2][[1]]
#[1] "traffic" "s"
```